# After JavaFX drag and drop I need to click twice to close window

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, javafx-11

In a simple drag and drop example program where strings can be dragged from a list cell to a text field, everything works fine, except that after a drop, the mouse does not behave normally: for example, I have to click twice on the window close button for the window to close.

However, in the following cases, everything works fine:

- Using a label instead of a text field (but the problem remains with a text area)
- Dropping a string into the text field from another application
- Dragging the string from the list cell onto another application

Clicking anywhere in the window also 'frees' the close button - even outside the list or the text field.

**Edited**: Below is a minimal working example (class `DnD` in package `dnd`). Note in particular the drag and drop handlers used on the field and on the list cell. To reproduce the problem: run the program, drag Banana from the list to the text field and then try to close the window. In my case I have to click twice.

```
package dnd;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldListCell;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Dnd extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new DndPanel(), 200, 300));
        stage.setTitle("Drag and drop");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class DndPanel extends VBox {

        public DndPanel() {
            super(10);
            TextField field = new TextField();
            ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
            list.setCellFactory(Dnd.DnDCell::new);
            list.getItems().addAll("Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Grapes", "Peach", "Pineapple");
            setPadding(new Insets(10));
            getChildren().addAll(field, list);

            field.setOnDragOver(ev -> {
                if (ev.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                    ev.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
                }
                ev.consume();
            });

            field.setOnDragDropped(ev -> {
                field.setText(ev.getDragboard().getString());
                ev.setDropCompleted(true);
                ev.consume();
            });

        }

    }

    public static class DnDCell extends TextFieldListCell<String> {
        public DnDCell(ListView<String> listView) {
            setOnDragDetected(ev -> {
                Dragboard dragboard = startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
                ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
                cc.putString(listView.getItems().get(getIndex()));
                dragboard.setContent(cc);
                ev.consume();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on JavaFX 11.0.2 from Gluon on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 with additional
JVM runtime option `-Djdk.gtk.version=2`.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with JavaFX 14 on Windows 10. Might be a Linux-specific issue.

Comment: I can confirm.  Having the same problem, also on Linux.